# How to set $ref to child component elements from parent component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-class-components

This is the parent component:

```
<template>
    <upload-block 
    :imSrc="LargeIcon"
    inputName="LargeIcon"
    :inputHandler="uploadAppIcon"
    inputRef="LargeIcon"
    :uploadClickHandler="handleUploadIcon"></upload-block>
</template>

<script>
export default class ParentCom extends Vue {
    //all props for <upload-block></upload-block> component defined here

    handleUploadIcon(event) {
        const icon_type = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-type");
        let appImgElem = this.$refs[icon_type];
        appImgElem.click();
    }

    async uploadAppIcon(event) {
        //code
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the child component:

```
<template>
    <div class="upload-div" @click="uploadClickHandler" :data-type="inputName">
        <img v-if="imSrc" :src="imSrc">
        <div v-else class="upload-icon-block">
        <span>
            <font-awesome-icon class="upload-icon" icon="arrow-circle-up" size="lg"></font-awesome-icon>
            <br>Click to upload
        </span>
        </div>
        <!-- <spinner variant="primary" :show="true"></spinner> -->
        <input style="display:none" type="file" :ref="inputRef" :name="inputName" @input="inputHandler">
    </div>
</template>

<script>

@Component({
    props: {
        imSrc: String,
        inputRef: String,
        inputName: String,
        inputHandler: Function,
        uploadClickHandler: Function
    }
})
export default class ChicdCom extends Vue {

}
</script>
```

The problem I am facing in the `handleUploadIcon` method in which I am not able to get the `input` element via `ref`.
It is showing `Cannot read property 'click' of undefined` in this line `appImgElem.click();`
But when I move the file input to the parent component, it's works fine. So can you plz help me how to set the ref to child component elements from parent as currently is it not setting.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you could add a `ref` to `upload-block` in the parent component:

```
<upload-block ref="upload" ... >
```

Then in the `handleUploadIcon` you can acces your input: `this.$refs.upload.$refs[icon_type]`

But I would try to move `handleUploadIcon` to the child component if I were you.